# magento 2: inventory_source_carrier_link table empty

Tags: magento2.4.6, multi-source-inventory, instore-pickup

I found one table `inventory_source_carrier_link` which is empty, I do not know why it is empty. We have three sources and stock. Two shipping methods enable: pickup and fixed. How Magento add data in `inventory_source_carrier_link` table.

This table belongs to this collection class `Magento\Inventory\Model\ResourceModel\SourceCarrierLink\Collection`

Anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the resposible class where it adds the entry in `inventory_source_carrier_link` table

```
class Magento\Inventory\Model\ResourceModel\Source
```

here is the code to add data in the table

```
/**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function save(AbstractModel $object)
    {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        $connection->beginTransaction();
        try {
            $object->isObjectNew(!$this->isObjectNotNew($object));
            parent::save($object);
            /** @var SourceInterface $object */
            $this->sourceCarrierLinkManagement->saveCarrierLinksBySource($object);
            $connection->commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $connection->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

And `saveCarrierLinksBySource` function saves the data in database table `inventory_source_carrier_link`  and it calling from this class `Magento\Inventory\Model\SourceCarrierLinkManagement`

```
/**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function saveCarrierLinksBySource(SourceInterface $source): void
    {
        $this->deleteCurrentCarrierLinks($source);

        $carrierLinks = $source->getCarrierLinks();
        if (null !== $carrierLinks && count($carrierLinks)) {
            $this->saveNewCarrierLinks($source);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param SourceInterface $source
     * @return void
     */
    private function deleteCurrentCarrierLinks(SourceInterface $source)
    {
        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $connection->delete(
            $this->resourceConnection->getTableName(SourceCarrierLink::TABLE_NAME_SOURCE_CARRIER_LINK),
            $connection->quoteInto('source_code = ?', $source->getSourceCode())
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param SourceInterface $source
     * @return void
     */
    private function saveNewCarrierLinks(SourceInterface $source)
    {
        $carrierLinkData = [];
        foreach ($source->getCarrierLinks() as $carrierLink) {
            $carrierLinkData[] = [
                'source_code' => $source->getSourceCode(),
                SourceCarrierLinkInterface::CARRIER_CODE => $carrierLink->getCarrierCode(),
                SourceCarrierLinkInterface::POSITION => $carrierLink->getPosition(),
            ];
        }

        $this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->insertMultiple(
            $this->resourceConnection->getTableName(SourceCarrierLink::TABLE_NAME_SOURCE_CARRIER_LINK),
            $carrierLinkData
        );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your request in data in this table, such as the source code, the carrier code, and the position, would help. You also need to specify the HTTP method and the endpoint for the API. The results of the data will point you in the correct direction.

Comment: I already gave the answer, based on your answer it is not appropriate of my question.